# Auto size font base on the width and without jquery or javascript

Tags: css, font-size

I see someone able to use em or % instead of px to auto size the font. I tried both of them, but it doesn't work for my scenario.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vw` which is the ratio of the viewport width.

```css
.text {
  font-size: 5vw; /* 5/100th of the view port width */
}
```

```html
<div class="text">I am variable</div>
```

Or you can use this plugin if you need a wider browser support, uses JS though: [**FitText**](http://fittextjs.com/)

Comment: This lack serious browser support though. Shouldn't be used.

Comment: Yup. But I see this will be the solution for the modern browsers. Future typography will be based on this.

Comment: Viewport units are IE9 and up...I'd call that pretty good support myself - [**CanIUse.com**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

Comment: it's not bad support, there's a gap with the stripped down mobile browsers too, which represent quite a high %, but, it's not difficult to use css to provide a fallback as rules are applied one by one in the order they are found in source, with the later one over-riding the earlier, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31217741/1249829

Answer (score 1):

As @Manoj Kumar said you can use vw but it's only supported for IE9 and up, if you want to cover more browsers you should also use a fall back by putting `font-size` in `em` before the `vw`.

```
.text {
  font-size: 3em; /* Whatever is equivalent to 5vw */
  font-size: 5vw; /* 5/100th of the view port width */
}
```